# Meta Tags on Frontpage

Tags: 7, meta-tags

It doesn't seem I can get my meta tags to appear on the `page--front.tpl.php` on a Drupal 7 site.

I feel like I have all the correct settings in the Meta tags module configuration, and I have cleared all caches. It works perfectly fine for all pages, just not the front page. This is driving me bonkers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

Below are the steps without touching the files and using the drupal admin interface.

1. Go to admin/config/search/metatags/config/global:frontpage/edit
2. Add the Page title, Description etc and Save
3. Refresh the front page and check. Done !!

Comment: Thanks. This is the correct answer. The rest is just a waste of time.

Comment: Yes, indeed, how did you know that?

Answer (score 4):

Try printing

```
<?php print render($page['content']['metatags']); ?>
```

in your `page.tpl.php` or `page--front.tpl.php` if youre using [Meta tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag)

Comment: Wouldn't that print metatags in body instead of head, or this doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

What module are you using for Metatags?

I believe the most popular one is metatags_quick. If you are using this I think you need to set the homepage metatags with the "Path-Based Metatags".  You should be able to find this at site.com/admin/config/search/metatags_quick/path_based

Comment: I wanted to do this, I have metatags quick, but how do you specify the homepage?  Im not sure how you specify the "frontpage" as a path?  Its perfect for 'views', but I cant figure out how to use for frontpage.

Comment: I finally figured this out.

Assuming you have Meta tags quick, you can go to the 'path based meta tags" tab and add the following as a path:

node

You then assign the appropriate metatag data.

-Mac

Answer (score 1):

Found a quick and easy solution that shows meta tag description on page view source HTML for anonymous visitor, also Bing SEO Analyzer detects.

1. Go to Meta Tag (Quick) settings from Configuration admin menu.
2. Under the section Create and Attach, check box for Description for Taxonomy Term
3. Click Attach
4. Click Submit
5. Go to admin Structure menu, Taxonomy, Section, List terms
6. Edit Home to add a description in the (Meta) Description field.

Works