# Metatags only appears on node pages, but don't appear on pages

Tags: meta-tags

I think this is a simple question. When I build a new node and add some meta-tags on this node, this meta-tags appears normally when I access the node directly (`http://www.example.com/node/<id>`, for example).

But, when a add this node on a page, and access the url of the page, the meta-tags do not appears on page.

I am using Drupal 7.24 and metatags (quick) module.

Thanks

**Update**: It's not the same question as asked in [Meta Tags on Frontpage](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37661/meta-tags-on-frontpage) and found a solution for my problem.

I needed to change a configuration in a specific page. So, I went to: **Content > Page > Selected the Content > Edit > Variants > Panel > Content.** Clicked on gear (right side) > Configuration > Selected Show Full Content.

Comment: are you using boost module ? and try to add this <?php print render($page['content']['metatags']); ?> in page.tpl and check it

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Bala! I've updated my question with the right answer for my problem because the team marked my question as duplicated. Anyway, thank you.